# SimpleDateFormat with Offset not recognized

Tags: java, java-7, simpledateformat

I needed to parse below Date coming from a web service.

```
2014-09-16T18:05:00.000-05:00
```

So I tried to created SimpleDateFormat object

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat
                                   ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

[JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) has below example and format given in the table that matches with my date format.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"            2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
```

However, I am getting below exception. I use jdk 1.7.0_55. Is there something I am missing ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'X'
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:768)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:575)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:500)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:475)
```

Comment: This runs fine with JDK 1.7 and JDK 1.8, but I get your exception with JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the version of Java you're using.  I bet you're actually using 6.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
```

The XXX format was added in 7.  Compare:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: The question explicitly states _I use jdk 1.7.0_55._ I guess the OP could be mistaken though. It does seem like the likely problem.

Comment: Yeah I think the questioner is mistaken on that.  The code works fine in 7.

Comment: java -version says 1.7. Eclipse compiler is set to 1.6. I will have to use 1.6 as server is running on 1.6. thinking of doing substring to exclude offset before converting to date